# How do I upgrade Flash Builder 4.6 to AIR 3.4?

Tags: air, adobe, flash-builder

AIR 3.4 was just released, with features like workers and native APN support.

How do I upgrade my existing Flash Builder installation to use the new AIR SDK?

Comment: IS StageVideo available for desktop Air with this sdk?

Comment: Not until 2013: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/whitepapers/roadmap.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Upgrading Flash Builder 4.6 to AIR 3.4**

Directions for Mac OSX.

1) Go to the **sdks** directory in your existing FB directory. On my machine it's /Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6/sdks.

**EDIT: I discovered that the merged Flex/AIR SDK is available here: http://gaming.adobe.com/getstarted/**

**The merged version of the instructions I had here before do not result in a stable SDK. Download the SDK from the link above, unzip it somewhere (be aware that it will overwrite your existing 4.6.0 directory if you unzip it under the sdks directory in Flash Builder), and then do the following.**

2) Add the new SDK to Flash Builder, under **Project -> Properties -> Flex Compiler -> Configure Flex SDKs**. Click **Add**, then choose the new SDK folder.

Add the following command line flag to your project, in the **"Additional compiler arguments"** field:

```
-swf-version=17
```

3) Change the target in your **-app.xml** file (root of your project directory) to 3.4:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.X">
```

to

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.4">
```

4) Start using new features like workers and iOS push notification support. Create engaging apps, bring in da mad coin, and retire young and happy after paying me a modest (percentage-wise, that is) stipend for enabling your new-found financial independence.

That should do it.

Comment: Tried the steps you mentioned above but unfortunately I'm still getting the "Namespace 0.0" error for my pre-existing AIR project. I can create a new AIR 3.4 project okay though for some reason. (I've even done a manual DIFF of the 2 .actionscriptProperties files and I don't see anything standing out as different.) Any additional suggestions?

Comment: What does the application tag look like in your -app.xml file now?

Comment: Looks like you'd expect, so far as I can tell. Opens with <application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.4">. If I create a new project, it will build and launch fine- even if I point its source path to the source path of my AIR 3.1 project (the one I tried and failed to upgrade) but for some reason, that original project refuses to build. Strange.

Comment: @brianvaughn Very odd... I haven't seen that. Perhaps a diff of the full directories instead of just the property files will show the problem.

Comment: When I checked today, 2013-Feb-11, the Gaming SDK available at the link doesn't include the Flex SDK but simply the compiled AIR 3.5.x SDK. You can update your Flex SDK locally by overalying it with the AIR SDK found in the Gaming SDK package. Simply duplicate your Flex SDK folder and rename it something sensible and then merge in the files found in AIR SDK folder (or in my case, a folder inside that called "air3.5_p5_sdk_asc3_mac011013") — now you have your original Flex SDK and another with AIR 3.5 capabilities

Comment: @MarkFox That's a shame. The combined SDK was the most reliable method to upgrade.

Comment: As of now the link redirects to this page http://www.adobe.com/devnet/games/gaming.html

Answer (score 0):

don't the following files:
    -air-config.xml
    -airmobile-config.xml
    -flex-config.xml
    -the build.xml files located in themes
    -flex-config.xml

need to be changed also in order to use the 3.4 sdk?