# flex 4.6 mobile project debug error using air 3.4

Tags: debugging, mobile, air, flash-builder

i've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083822/how-do-i-upgrade-flash-builder-4-6-to-air-3-4) in order to flashbuilder 4.6 to use air sdk 3.4. no problems, or hiccups with the update.
the only problem is when i try to debug a mobile project using this sdk, either for android or ios i get the following error:

> Process terminated without establishing connection to debugger.
>
> invalid application descriptor: Unknown namespace:
>   http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.4
>
> Launch command details:  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash
>   Builder 4.6\sdks\4.6.1\bin\adl.exe" -runtime "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.6.1\runtimes\air\win"
>   -profile mobileDevice -screensize 640x920:640x960 -XscreenDPI 326 -XversionPlatform IOS "C:\Users\joao\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\teste34\bin-debug\teste34-app.xml" "C:\Users\joao\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\teste34\bin-debug"

Comment: i've re-configured the sdk and now when i click on run or debug i'm presented with this error instead.  Process terminated unexpectedly.

error while loading initial content


Launch command details:  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.6.1\bin\adl.exe" -runtime "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.6.1\runtimes\air\win" -profile mobileDevice -screensize 640x920:640x960 -XscreenDPI 326 -XversionPlatform IOS "C:\Users\joao\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\teste34444\bin-debug\teste34444-app.xml" "C:\Users\joao\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\teste34444\bin-debug"

Answer (score 4):

i've also got this problem.
following is what i've done:
1:create a new empty mobile application and debug it runs
2:open the new app's '{appname}-app.xml' file , find the 'xmlns' property in application root node for example

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.1">
```

3:replace the row of your old application
So i think the problem is your air sdk can not support the 3.4 version